# Is it possible to configure one Facebook app to be used across multiple domains?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to configure one  Facebook app to be used across multiple domains?

how can i authenticate user with one APP_ID and Multiple Domain?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible for security reasons. The most you can do is using subdomains.

Comment: it means i can use multiple subdomains for one facebook app by specifying  single app_domain.  for e.g  my app_domain is mydomain.com and i am having 3 sub domains from this like user1.mydomain.com,user2.mydomain.com and user3.mydomain.com . so will it work for single app  or i need to create 3 apps to overcome of this problem?

Comment: Yes you can just google it you will find a lot of resources.